# Logic Issue in IIS 8 and Centralized Certificates

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, centralized-certificates

So We have noticed a weird issue happening in our (soon to be production) network.

We have 3 IIS Servers, using shared configuration and using Centralized Certificates.  Each site has up to 6 bindings (3 for non www for each of the hosts, 3 for www for each of the hosts)
[Sample IIS Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6jHH.png)
Each of the SSL Binding's are configured like this
[IIS Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58NWm.png)

When we go to the non www version of the site the SSL certificate is picked up fine, however when we go to the www version a mismatch is thrown and it tries to use the hosts wildcard certificate.   If I disable centralized certificates, install the cert on the host and set it in the IIS binding for the WWW entries everything works..

Kind of stumped on this one

Comment: Since you have 6 bindings, you need six certificate files matching the host names in Centralized Certificate Store. Do you have only three at this moment?

Comment: So for example than,  a certificate file must match the binding name 1:! aka

host1.com : host1.com.pfx
www.host1.com : www.host1.com.pfx  

Even if the host1.com.pfx caries the alt name of the www?

Comment: The certificate naming convention is just like that.